# How To insert data in mysql database using ajax in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to validate my form and insert the data in mysql database using ajax.Neither on submit validation is happening nor data is being inserted.I am making this in codeigniter framework. I am new bie to ajax.I am not able to figure out where am going wrong .Here is my code

View :

```
      <script  type="text/javascript">
      function validate_name(first_name){
        if(first_name.trim() == '' || first_name.length == 0){
        $('.first_name').show();
         $('.first_name').text('Please enter your name');
         return false;
    } else {
      $('.first_name').hide();
      return true;
    }
  }


  function validate_email(email_id){
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i);

    if(email_id.trim() == '' || email_id.length == 0){
      $('.email-id').show();
      $('.email-id').text('Please enter email address');
      return false;
    }else if(!pattern.test(email_id)) {
      $('.email-id').show();
      $('.email-id').text('Please enter valid email address');
      return false;
    } else {
      $('.email-id').hide();
      return true;
    }
  }

  function validate_inquiry_form(first_name,email_id){
    var username_validate = validate_name(first_name);
    var email_validate = validate_email(email_id);

    if(username_validate == true && email_validate == true){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  $('#submit_enquiry').click(function(){

      var first_name      = $("input[name=first_name]").val();
      var last_name       = $("input[name=last_name]").val();
      var dob             = $("input[name=dob]").val(); 
      var gender          = $("input[name=gender] :radio:checked").val();
      var email_id        = $("input[name=email_id]").val();
      var password        = $("input[name=password]").val();
      var address         = $("input[name=address]").val();
      var phone           = $("input[name=phone]").val();
      var zipcode         = $("input[name=zipcode]").val();

      var validate_form = validate_inquiry_form(first_name,email_id);
      if(validate_form == true){
        $.ajax({
          url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>member/register',
          type:'POST',
          data:{ 
                  first_name : first_name ,last_name : last_name ,dob : dob ,male : male ,female : female , email_id : email_id ,password : password ,phone : phone , address : address , zipcode : zipcode
               },

          success: function(data) {

            console.log(data);
          }
        });
      } else {
        return false;
      }
      return false;
  });
</script>


        <form id="registration-form">
          <div class="register">
                    <div class="row">
                          <div class="col1">
                              <label for="first_name">First Name<span>*</span></label> <br/>
                              <input type="text" name="first_name"/>
                    <li class="first_name error"></li>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col2">
                                Last Name<br/>
                                <input type="text" name="last_name"/>
                          </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                          <div  class="col1">
                                Date Of Birth <br/>
                                <input type="text" name="dob"/>
                          </div>

                            <div  class="col2">
                              Gender
                              <br/>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" /> Male
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" /> Female
                            </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                          <div class="col1">
                                Email<br/>
                                <input type="text" name="email_id"/>
                    <li class="email-id error"></li>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col2">
                                Password<br/>
                                <input type="password" name="password"/>
                          </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                  Address<br/>
                                  <textarea name="address" rows="2" ></textarea>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                          <div class="col1">
                                Zipcode<br/>
                                <input type="text" name="zipcode"/>
                          </div>
                           <div class="col2">
                                  Phone<br/>
                                  <input type="text" name="phone"/>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col3">
                          <input class="" type="button" id="submit_enquiry" name="submit_enquiry" value="Submit Enquiry" />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
          </div>
        </form>
```

Controller:

```
public function register_user()
    {
        $register_user  = $this->member_model->add_user();
        if($register_user)
        {                
            return true;
        }  
        else 
        {  
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Model :

```
public function add_user()
{
    $add_user = array(
                    'mem_name'=> $this->input->post('first_name'),
                    'mem_lastname'=> $this->input->post('last_name'),
                    'mem_dob'=> $this->input->post('dob'),
                    'mem_gender'=> $this->input->post('gender'),
                    'mem_email'=> $this->input->post('email_id'),
                    'mem_address'=> $this->input->post('address'),
                    'mem_zipcode'=> $this->input->post('zipcode'),
                    'mem_phone'=> $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'mem_password'=> $this->input->post('password'),

    );

    $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $add_user);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    return  $insert_id;
}
```

Please help me ....

Comment: When submitting form I would use form_validation on the controller side,

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? The AJAX request itself? Handling it in PHP? Writing data to the database?

Answer (score 0):

change in this in your ajax add apostrophe (')

```
data:{ 
                  'first_name' : first_name ,'last_name' : last_name ,'dob' : dob , etc...
               },
```

add this in your controler member

```
    function register(){
       $add_user = array(
                    'mem_name'=> $this->input->post('first_name'),
                    'mem_lastname'=> $this->input->post('last_name'),
                    'mem_dob'=> $this->input->post('dob'),
                    'mem_gender'=> $this->input->post('gender'),
                    'mem_email'=> $this->input->post('email_id'),
                    'mem_address'=> $this->input->post('address'),
                    'mem_zipcode'=> $this->input->post('zipcode'),
                    'mem_phone'=> $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'mem_password'=> $this->input->post('password'),
      );
      $this->member_model->add_user($add_user);
    }
```

in your member_model

```
function add_user($add_user){
    $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $add_user);
}
```

Comment: I tries your solution , but Its not working..Neither form validation nor data is entering in db @ Arif

Comment: What form validation? I don't see that code here, just js form validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery validate and use ajay on submit handler.  Please try following code:

````js
$(function () {
    $("#FormId").validate({
        errorElement: 'span', errorClass: 'help-block',
        rules: {
            Tag: {
                required: true
            },
           Table: {
                required: true
            },
            Field: {
                required: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            Tag: {
                required: "Tag is required."
            },
            Table: {
                required: "Table is required."
            },
            Field: {
                required: "Field is required."
            },
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').children('span.help-block').remove();
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.closest('.form-group'));
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $("#saveButton").button('loading');
            $.post('', $("#FormId").serialize(), function (data) {
                //Write your code here
            });
        }
    });
});```
````